# postMessage always returns wrong data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postmessage

My aim is to click a button in current tab and it will open a new tab, and use the postMessage API in the new tab's Chrome dev tools:

```
window.opener.postMessage({deliveryId: 18042548, materialId: 1051041576634029702},'*')
```

The current tab has already added the `onmessage` event, and it will check the origin, `console.log` the data:

```
window.addEventListener("message", this.syncDirectMaterialTag)
syncDirectMaterialTag = async e => {
    if ('http://beta-ace.jd.com' === e.origin) {
      console.log(e.data)
      //const res = await queryDirMaterialTag(mapper)
    }
  }
```

But it always returns me the same wrong message whatever I have post:

```
deliveryId: 18042548
materialId: 1051041576634029700
```

How can it be ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it.

The reason is that JavaScript lost accuracy.

So the materialId's type should be String:

```
window.opener.postMessage({deliveryId: 18042548, materialId: '1051041576634029702'},'*')
```